# Euclidean distance between random variables

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, probability-distributions

Let $X$ and $Y$ be independent random vectors over measurable, bounded subsets of positive measure $A$, $B\subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$. Assume $X$ and $Y$ are absolutely continuous, and let $f$, $g$ be their densities. What can we say about $\|X - Y\|$? Is it, too, an absolutely continuous random variable? Can I explicitly write its density by the means of $f$ and $g$?

Best I could do is $$
P(\|X-Y\| \le t) = \int_{A\times B} f(x)\, g(y) \, \chi_{[0,t]}(\| x - y\|) \, \mathrm{d}x \, \mathrm{d} y.
$$ The characteristic function is not differentiable in the usual sense, so I cannot differentiate in respect to $t$ and call it a day.